# Dual entries in logback file configuration

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, log4j2

I am trying to configure rolling file appender in logback. I see that logs are repeating in both by catalina.out(using tomcat server) and myfile.log. Please let me know how to ensure only system logs goes to catalina and rest of application log comes into my custom log file.

Also, some times I see that some logs are not written either in catalina.out or mylogs.log, but the logic is executed completely which means the logs should be written. Can any one throw some thoughts on this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>${catalina.base}/logs/mylogs.log</file>
      <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
         <Pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </encoder>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
         <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/mylogs.log.%i.%d.zip</fileNamePattern>
         <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
         </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      </rollingPolicy>
   </appender>
   <logger name="com.myproject" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
   </logger>
   <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
   </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have a look at the logback `additivity` flag.

Comment: I have made additivity flag as false which means logs of com.myproject should be appending only to FILE appender. If this understanding is incorrect, please advise.

Comment: I see that some logs are missed while writing into my file. Please advise if this is something related to configuration. As those class files are under same package com.myproject, I dont think there is a problem with log additivity setup. Please let me know.

Comment: I also have this problem
Someone did not find a solution?
additivity is false